# PHP/Wordpress Session Configuration

Tags: php, wordpress, session

I'm trying to integrate a [quiz/survey plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-survey-and-quiz-tool/) with an existing Wordpress site.  Everything is working well, except that if the user lets a quiz/survey sit idle for awhile (30 minutes is long enough to trigger it) they will be greeted with the following error message when trying to submit their reply:

> PHP Sessions error. Check your sessions settings.

I did as the error message suggests and checked my PHP session settings.  More specifically, I edited the server's `php.ini` file and set the session timeout to two hours.  I thought that would have done the trick, but when I tested again I got the same issue after 30 minutes of inactivity.

So my questions are:

1. Does Wordpress maintain a session that is different than the one that PHP maintains?  If so how is it configured?
2. Is `php.ini` the correct place to be configuring my session settings?
3. Has anyone seen this error before, and if so, what was the solution?

Comment: Yes, usually php.ini is the corrent place to change session settings (of cource you can change most of them at runtime). But what setting did you change exactly (there are two main settings: cookie lifetime and garbadge collector if you handle session using cookies)? Did you look when your session cookie expires in browser? And the error that you see simply happens when a users is not on the first step, but there are no cookie variables avaliable in Shortcode.php of Wpsqt.

Comment: @XzKto - I changed the cookie lifetime setting only.  But checking in the browser my PHPSESSION cookie lists an expiry of "At End Of Session", which isn't what it should be.  Do I need to do anything special to get the changes in php.ini to be picked up.

Comment: First of all you need to change session.gc_maxlifetime too(it defaults to 24 minutes) or no matter how much your cookie lives PHP will automatically delete the session file(not cookie, real file with data) after that interval. When changing session.cookie_lifetime you must have in mind that it sets cookie expiration time relative to server time - not client's time. And what php.ini did you change exactly?If you installed PHP as Apache module then there will be another php.ini that will be used by Apache.Just check with phpinfo() if you really changed settings or look at the exact php.ini path.

Comment: @XzKto - Thanks, setting the `gc_maxlifetime option` seems to have fixed it.  Strangely my PHPSESSION cookie is still listed as expiring "At End Of Session", but the survey now works correctly.

Comment: Did you check your phpinfo() output? If it is set correctly there then maby Wordpress sets it himself (there are a lot of ways to do it). I never used Wordpress myself, so I can't really help you here. Just one more thing: beware of big gc_maxlifetime value - an attacker can easily exploit it for a Dos attack - with a slow garbage collector you will have a lot of garbage session files which can slow down your server or even mess with some filesystems.

Comment: @XzKto - Yes, `phpinfo()` output displays all the correct values.  Not sure what's going on in that respect.  Is it possible that two PHP instances are installed, one that Wordpress is using, and a separate one that I get when I run PHP from the command line?

Comment: Yes, of course, it is default behaviour but there are not two PHP instances - just two different configuration files. For example I have /etc/php5/cli/php.ini for command line PHP and /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini for apache module PHP. When running phpinfo() you can even look what configuration file it uses. But if changing one of your settings helped you the chances are that you are editing the right config file and that Wordpress simply sets that variable itself. But you should try to output phpinfo() from web server just to be sure (simply file with just "<?php phpinfo();").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue,

I fixed it by making sure `/var/lib/php/session` folder was set `0777` for permissions, deleted all the session files and did a graceful restart of the server.

Sessions messages went away and voting worked.

Comment: Hi I am having the same problem. Where is that folder? is this in the WP installation or somewhere on the hosting server?btw I am using webhost4life to host my websites.

Comment: Hey There. You would need root access to the server itself to find these, or ask your provider where you can find them. Different hosting providers will have them in different locations, sometimes apache is configured to place each users session files in their home folders.