# Theme twentyfourteen error with session

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

Currently, I am develop one website that use theme Twentyfourteen. Immediately, I noticed that this theme has an error with session time.

Has anyone have any idea about this??

Comment: have a look on this link..may it solve your issue [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6926421/php-wordpress-session-configuration)